# SKTexture doesn't change properly

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

So like the title says, my SKTexture doesn't change as I would expect it to.

This is how I declare my singleton in my player Class:

```
    static let sharedInstance = NHPlayer()
```

I have this function:

```
func setSkin(name: String) {
    print("Before : \(body.texture)") // Print default SKTexture
    body.texture = atlas.textureNamed("\(name)-body")
    print("After : \(body.texture)") // print the SKTexture I choose in game
}
```

I call body like so :

```
func loadAppearance() {
    let name = getCurrentSkin()
    print(name)

    body = SKSpriteNode(texture: atlas.textureNamed("\(name)-body"))
    addChild(body)
}
```

I got the name of the texture I want using this function:

```
func getCurrentSkin() -> String {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var name = defaults.valueForKey("currentSkin")
    if name == nil {
        name = "default"
    }
    return "\(name!)"
}
```

Calling setSkin here:

```
func play() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let current = charactersList.filter{ $0.name == nameLabel.text?.lowercaseString }
    removeFromParent()
    defaults.setObject(current.first?.name, forKey: "currentSkin")
    NHPlayer.sharedInstance.setSkin((current.first?.name)!)
    GameScene.sharedInstance.restart()
}
```

It prints the good texture name, but the texture isn't loaded, I have to close the game and reopen it to let the SKTexture change happen.

Any ideas on how to fix?

If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: will need to see more code,  is "body" the correct instance you should be editing, is update/draw being called correctly,  etc.  There are a lot that could be going wrong right now.

Comment: i edited my first post

Comment: you need to supply us with the actual functions, don't cut it short for us

Comment: Sorry, i hope it's more clear now

Comment: You still are not showing when setskin gets called, show us that

Comment: Edited again, sorry for that.

Comment: oy,  a singleton,  not sure if thats the approach you want to take here.  Are you positive your singleton is not changing?

Comment: What do you mean by changing ?

Comment: as in it is not really a singleton, you are assigning sharedInstance multiple times

Comment: This is the only time i use NHPlayer.sharedInstance

Comment: no, where do you create it, not use it

Comment: static let sharedInstance = NHPlayer()
i create it just before the init in my NHPlayer class

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not calling NHPlayer() elsewhere than on your player class?

Looks like when you assign the new texture, it is assigning for sure, but to another instance and not the singleton

Comment: That was it, I forgot that i had a player = NHPlayer in my gamescene, everything works fine now :D